# Javascript background process in IOSSafari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, background-process, deep-linking

I try to redirect the user to app if they have installed in their device else redirects them to app download page (iTunes). 
I want to capture exact url where the client goes at last(app Url or web Url).

Is there any background process to capture which url the client presents?

```
if (IOSSafari) 
{    
    window.location.href = appUrl;
    var startTime = new Date();
    setTimeout(function() 
    {                
        if (new Date() - startTime < 600) 
        {                 
            if (window.location.href != webUrl) 
                window.location.href = webUrl;
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

My Attempt(I tried as below):-

```
if (IOSSafari) 
{    
    callback(appUrl); // first callback to my server to identify the user presence
    window.location.href = appUrl;
    var startTime = new Date();
    setTimeout(function() 
    {                
        if (new Date() - startTime < 600) 
        {                 
            if (window.location.href != webUrl) 
            {
                // second callback to my server to identify the user presence 
                callback(appUrl); 
                window.location.href = webUrl;
            }
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Case 1 App is installed:-

1. User A enters
2. My first callback works, user gets redirected to app
3. Now table have single entry with appUrl for User A. This works as expected since the user presents in app(appUrl).

Case 2 App is not installed:-

1. User A enters
2. My first callback works, user gets redirected to app
3. Since app is not presents in device it says safari cannot open this page
4. Second callback works and user redirect to app download page
5. Now table have 2 entries(entry with appUrl and entry with webUrl) for User A instead of single entry(entry with webUrl since user presents in download page)

Answer (score 1):

One simplest way to capture that value is use a client side cookie.

```
document.cookie="lasturl="+xyz+";path=/";
//xyz is webUrl or appUrl , so write the above line before calling window.location.href=...

document.cookie="lasturl="+deeplinkUrl+";path=/";
window.location.href=deeplinkUrl;

//or

document.cookie="lasturl="+webUrl+";path=/";
window.location.href=webUrl;
```

Later you can check the cookie value for "lasturl"

Comment: Thanks. If the redirection to app done successfully, then how can we get cookie value since we are in native app not in browser?

Comment: @DurgaGanesh: Original question: "I want to capture exact url"; says nothing about that info to be available to the native app. Please supply detailed background info; avoid the XY problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Ruud Thanks.Please see my edit. Can I invoke my callback after user redirects to native app? From my opinion its not possible. If I am correct what is the alternative and intelligent way to predict?

Comment: (Got yourself a new name?) @Inaccessible: Sorry to say this, but even after your edit, there is no real question. You say your callbacks work, resulting in (potentially distinguishable) log entries in your backend. Please state your problem. Try to imagine I am not a psychic.

Comment: @Ruud Thanks for showing interest. My question is how can I track whether user redirected to app or download page?

Answer (score 1):

In the below code us a new parameter called "token" with a random value.

```
if (IOSSafari) {    
        callback(appUrl); // first callback to my server to identify the user presence
        var tokenID=parseInt(Math.random()*100000);
        window.location.href = appUrl+"?token="+tokenID;
        var startTime = new Date();
        setTimeout(function() {                
            if (new Date() - startTime < 600) {                 
                if (window.location.href != webUrl) {
                   callback(appUrl); // second callback to my server to identify the user presence 
                   window.location.href = webUrl+"?token="+tokenID;
                }
            }
        }, 500);
 }
```

Design your "webUrl" in such a way that it does 2 tasks:

1. delete the existing entry in table with tokenid=XXXXX [Note that the token value XXXXX is passed same both the times]
2. redirect to the app download url.

This way you would have only one entry in the table, as the "webUrl" takes care of deleting the unnecessary previous entry identified by the tokenid.

Comment: Its not reliable. It leads unnecessary works. But I like your way of thought. Thanks. I need to prevent extra entries before it gets saved in DB.

Comment: Also my client prefer logs rather than database. I don't think we can modify logs after both entries registered there.

Answer (score 0):

For the AppStore link have a tracking url that just redirects to iTunes after logging the event

For the App being installed, could you possibly make the app ping a tracking url when it notices it has been opened by your website? (this is technically possible but it will require and app update on iTunes to include code to do this)

When the app gets:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```